# How to get value of input field in javascript after change

Tags: javascript

In my form, an input field is having value `'X'`, I am updating the same to `'Y'` in javascript as below.
`document.getElementById("FIELDID").value = 'Y';`

but when I get the value for same field in javascript after change I am getting it as `'X'` instead of `'Y'`.

`var a = document.getElementById("FIELDID").value;
alert(a); // it gives 'X'`

How can I get updated value of input field after change in javascript?

**Update:**
Sorry for the trouble, actually in form I am doing some calculations and updating the total in final field. There was issue in calculation part hence the whenever I get the total value in javascript it was returning old value. Issue was resolved after rectifying the calculation.

Comment: Please share a **runnable** [mcve] with us that highlights the error

Comment: Add your code please

Comment: From what you described this should work, so there seems to be going on something behind the scenes. Just to clarify, the update works, you see "Y" in your input field and still `.value` returns "X"?

Answer (score 0):

You can start by choosing and modifying any of them, according to your needs.

```js
document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
  alert(e.target.value);
});

/**
* document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener('change', function(e){
*  alert(e.target.value);
* });
**/
```

```html
<input type='text' id='foo'>
```